# Track amount of time visitor spends on a website

Tags: php, session, analytics

I want to track a how long a user spends on my website. I'm not too worried about it being down to the second it can be a 10-15% off and it will be ok I want more of an estimate. 
I was thinking of using sessions once the user logs in it will generate a session variable that will track the seconds. Using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];` I will be able to find out the difference between the time that was declared when they hit the previous page to this page.

The problem I'm having is what happens if the user spends 10 mins on the site then closes the browser. The session variable will be lost after it expires. I need some way of updating this variable to the database. Having the value update after every after every page click seems like an excessive amount of sql update queries and it was because of this I didn't want to use javascript and ajax.

Is there a way to save a session variable on expire? So once `$_SESSION['timeonline']` expires update it to the database

Comment: Any reason for not using http://www.google.com/analytics ?

Comment: because analytics does not offer tracking for individual users that are logged in only for the whole site in general. Ive already got analytics set up anyway which is what made me want to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will find any solution involving your PHP backend other than "pinging" your backend every couple of seconds. And like you said, this is both bad and still not 100% working.

Why reinvent the wheel. Use a tracking tool. PIWIK is open source and easily set up. It does what all tracking tools do, including "Time spent on Website". Although visitors who just close a bworser after 10min of inactivity will probably not be tracked right there too.

http://piwik.org/